# Raspberry Pi + neopixel: If brightness of RGB LEDs are reduced, does that mean certain colors cannot be rendered?

Tags: colors, raspberry-pi, rgb, led, neopixel

Referring to the python library  `neopixel` (rpi_ws281x), to control WS2812B RGB LED strips, does trimming the brightness by scaling the byte for each sub-LED in a pixel from 255 to 127 limits us from rendering certain colors?

According to the library, for dimming purposes, the following code is executed:

```
def setBrightness(self, brightness):
        """Scale each LED in the buffer by the provided brightness.  A brightness
        of 0 is the darkest and 255 is the brightest.
        """
        ws.ws2811_channel_t_brightness_set(self._channel, brightness)
```

However, if I would like to render the color of RGB (255, 187, 120) at 50% brightness: seems to me, the data frame bits are <strike>clipped</strike> capped at a maximum (127, 127, 127) per pixel - according to code above, by which, the above color is not displayable?

Am I right?

Could anyone explain how the brightness control/dimming function from that library works?
Shouldn't it decrease the PWM duty cycle to decrease brightness (power)?

Please explain. Thank you.

UPDATE:

By plotting brightness against CCT, at lower brightnesses (100% --> 75% --> 50% --> 25%), the CCT increases. How to correct this?

```
import colour
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.array([255, 187, 120])
data75 = data*0.75
data50 = data*0.5
data25 = data*0.25

datas = [data, data75, data50, data25]
methods = ['daylight','kang2002','mccamy1992','hernandez1999']

def rgb2cct(x,y):
    RGB = np.array(x)
    XYZ = colour.sRGB_to_XYZ(RGB / 255)
    xy = colour.XYZ_to_xy(XYZ)
    CCT = colour.xy_to_CCT(xy, y)
    #print(CCT)
    return CCT

X =[100,75,50,25]
Y = []

for j in methods:
    print(j)
    for k,v in enumerate(datas):
        u = rgb2cct(v,j)
        Y.append(u)

def chunks(lst, n):
    for i in range(0, len(lst), n):
        yield lst[i:i + n]

plot = list(chunks(Y,4))

for i,j in zip(plot,methods):
    plt.plot(X,i, label = j)

plt.axhline(y=3200, color = 'black', linewidth=0.5)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color values are not clipped, but multiplied by the brightness factor. So `255` turns into `127`, `127` into `63`.

The color `(255, 187, 120)` would then become `(127, 93, 60)`.

This means that you will evenly lose all the brighter "variants" of the colors.

A CCT of 3200K, which would be defined as `(255, 187, 120)`, would still be 3200K at `(127, 93, 60)`, since the relation between the colors stays the same. If you had LEDs with a higher dynamic range, 3200K could be defined as `(1023, 375, 239)`.

But one thing to notice is that brightness is [not a linear function](https://www.ledinside.com/knowledge/2017/7/how_to_choose_dimming_curves_linear_or_logarithmic) in these LEDs. Usually the brightness jump from `0` to `16` is much more noticeable than the one from `111` to `127`, so yes, in that sense you will lose colors. You would have more accurate colors by putting a black fabric over the LED which let's through only 50% of the light.

Comment: Hi, the reason for color importance in my application is to display and sustain the right Correlated Color Temperature (CCT). A CCT of 3200 K requires RGB values of  ```(255, 187, 120) ```. Thus, I was thinking of displaying the right color with reduced power based on user demand. In that case,  maybe, I should switch off 50% of the pixels.